# Windows Forms - passing object to modal form to populate and then pass back

Tags: windows, forms, modal-dialog, pass-by-reference

I have an UltraGrid that uses a Dictionary as its data source.  I want to pass the dictionary to another (modal) form to get manipulated and have the changes be reflected in the dictionary on the parent form.

I am able to pass in the dictionary to the child form, fart around on it to my hearts delight, but none of the changes are reflected in the dictionary on the parent form.  I believe that this is because the dictionary parameter on the child form isn't referencing the same object.

I really don't want to pass in the dictionary by ref.  The modal form has a private constructor and a public static method, ShowForm().  I don't use an instance on it.  Could someone please throw me a bone?

Comment: Could you show some of your code? The part where you open the child form and pass the dictionary.

Comment: Thanks for the response, Steve.  I was able to get it working and posted the solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I was able to get this to work by doing 2 things:

1) Making sure the dictionary is initialized before passing it to the child form, rather than initializing a null dictionary in the child form.

2) Assigning the dictionary back to the data source on the grid when the child form closes.

Here is the code for the parent form showing it in action:

```
private void addColorCodeLabel_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
    {
        var assignedColorCodes = 
            (Dictionary<string, string>)this.subtypeColorCodesUltraGrid.DataSource;

        //Initialize a null dictionary so that SubtypeColorCodeForm will reference the same dictionary.
        if (assignedColorCodes == null)
            assignedColorCodes = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        SubtypeColorCodeForm.ShowForm(this, new ImageServerProxy(this.tbImagingUri.Text), 
            assignedColorCodes);

        //Assign the updated dictionary back to the data source.
        this.subtypeColorCodesUltraGrid.DataSource = assignedColorCodes;
    }
```